# Do I need to lock singleton in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, singleton

Here is my code:

```
public class RouteSingleton
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> _dealCatLinks;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _sectionLinks;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _categoryLinks;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _materials;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _vendors;
    public RouteSingleton(IDealService dealService
        , ICategoryService categoryService
        , IVendorService vendorService)
    {


        this._dealCatLinks = dealService.GetDealCatLinks("PLV").Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
        this._sectionLinks = categoryService.GetSectionLinks("PLV").Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
        this._categoryLinks = categoryService.GetMainCategoryLinks("PLV")
            .Where(x => !_sectionLinks.ContainsKey(x)).Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);
        this._vendors = _vendorService.GetVendorLinks("PFB").Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);

    }

    public bool IsDealCategory(string slug)
    {
        return _dealCatLinks.ContainsKey(slug);
    }

    public bool IsSectionUrl(string slug)
    {
        return _sectionLinks.ContainsKey(slug);
    }

    public bool IsCategory(string slug)
    {
        return _categoryLinks.ContainsKey(slug);
    }       

    public bool IsVendor(string slug)
    {
        return _vendors.ContainsKey(slug);
    }
}
```

Here is how I register in `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<RouteSingleton, RouteSingleton>();
```

And I use the `singleton` in `route constraints` like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("category", "{slug}", defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" }, constraints: new { slug = new CategoryConstraint(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<RouteSingleton>()) });
```

1. I wonder do I need to `lock threads` in my `RouteSingleton.cs` or my code will work fine under lots of users on application start?
2. If I need to lock what way you can suggest to me?
3. What will happen if I don't?

Comment: On a side note: It has nothing to do with audio, so it's single**ton**, not single**tone**. That aside, your singleton class may have some serious issues, as it injects services which are most likely **not** singletons themselves, so you may leak memory allocated by these services as they will never be released unless the application shuts down. For example if you are using tracked DbContext (EF Core), then the memory for both the tracked entities as well as the DbContext itself and possible a connection handle maybe be kept in memory indefinitely

Comment: @Tseng I updated my question. Could you please is that what you did mean?

Comment: That's a bit better, but not enough, because the container will still hold an reference on these dependencies (even when they are scoped or transient because the container tracks the reference so it can dispose then when the container is disposed). You would be better off using `IMemoryCache` inside an scoped service

Comment: @Tseng Thanks a lot. Will change then post update.

Comment: No need to update it, as a new question if its still unclear

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you don't need to lock anything.  It is a singleton and will only be constructed once, and the only thing you are doing with your private dictionaries in multiple threads simultaneously is calling `ContainsKey`, which should be quite safe since nothing else can be modifying the dictionary while you are calling `ContainsKey`.

However, if you were modifying those dictionaries after the constructor, it would be an entirely different story-- you would either have to use a lock/mutex/etc. to protect access to them or use a thread safe dictionary, such as `ConcurrentDictionary`.  As it is currently written, you should be fine.

Comment: No, I will not modify my dictionaries. It's like internal memory cache. Thanks for your time, Tim.